# Package installation error after reinstalling poetry

Tags: python, windows

The error appeared after reinstalling poetry.
Python 3.11.5
Poetry (version 1.6.1)
Windows 10
Most of the errors I found were related to creating a virtual environment (poetry install).

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19045.3448]
(c) Корпорация Майкрософт (Microsoft Corporation). Все права защищены.

C:\Users\Стёпа\Desktop\111>poetry new .
Created package 111 in .

C:\Users\Стёпа\Desktop\111>poetry check
All set!

C:\Users\Стёпа\Desktop\111>poetry install
Updating dependencies
Resolving dependencies... (0.1s)

Writing lock file

Installing the current project: 111 (0.1.0)

C:\Users\Стёпа\Desktop\111>poetry add loguru
Using version ^0.7.2 for loguru

Updating dependencies
Resolving dependencies... (0.2s)

Package operations: 3 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals

  • Installing colorama (0.4.6): Failed

  CalledProcessError

  Command '['C:\\Users\\Стёпа\\AppData\\Local\\pypoetry\\Cache\\virtualenvs\\111-O89wkeCb-py3.11\\Scripts\\python.exe', '-I', '-W', 'ignore', '-']' returned non-zero exit status 1.

  at ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\subprocess.py:571 in run
       567│             # We don't call process.wait() as .__exit__ does that for us.
       568│             raise
       569│         retcode = process.poll()
       570│         if check and retcode:
    →  571│             raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args,
       572│                                      output=stdout, stderr=stderr)
       573│     return CompletedProcess(process.args, retcode, stdout, stderr)
       574│
       575│

The following error occurred when trying to handle this error:


  EnvCommandError

  Command ['C:\\Users\\Стёпа\\AppData\\Local\\pypoetry\\Cache\\virtualenvs\\111-O89wkeCb-py3.11\\Scripts\\python.exe', '-I', '-W', 'ignore', '-'] errored with the following return code 1

  Error output:
  SyntaxError: Non-UTF-8 code starting with '\xd1' in file <stdin> on line 9, but no encoding declared; see https://peps.python.org/pep-0263/ for details
...
```

reinstalling poetry (+clearing the entire cache) and python

Comment: This is my first question on stackoverflow please be understanding.